# Dse Graph Schema change on production mode

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I went through [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/graph/QuickStartStudio.html) tutorial on  Datastax website (link added below), which say changing schema on production mode can have anomalous behavior.

> "First, set the schema mode to Development. Development is a more
>   lenient mode that allows schema to be added at any time during
>   testing. Also allow full scans for testing purposes to inspect the
>   data with broad graph traversals. For production, Production schema
>   mode should be set to prevent interactive schema changes that can lead
>   to anomalous behavior, and full scans should be turned off".

**Does Datastax consider creating new VertexLabels and EdgeLabels on production a schema change?**

Answer (score 1):

Studio dev here...

> Does Datastax consider creating new VertexLabels and EdgeLabels on production a schema change?

Yes, but the advice you pasted regarding schema mode (production vs development) is strictly given within the context of the tutorial. Meaning, during development it can be beneficial to relax the schema mode, but when you go to production you will want to set the schema mode to Production. Note that this does not prevent you from explicitly modifying the schema. It prevents data-driven schema changes from occurring implicitly based on the data being written.

Comment: I have a use case in which `Vertex label` , `EdgeLabel` and `properties` (`Vertex and `Edge` properties) are to be dynamically created in production mode. Is it feasible in `DSE graph` and what I should care about most if I have large data may be `Million edges in coming 6 months`.